# How can I solve conflicting lifetime requirements for a &PathBuf passed to a closure?

Tags: rust

I have a `PathBuf` that needs to be passed to a closure to resolves paths, I've added some lifetimes to solve other issues that rustc was complaining about, but now I get the following error: `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirement`. I'm not sure how to solve it or where to find documentation to understand how to solve it.

```rust
fn read_tag_file<'a>(
    path: &'a PathBuf,
    cwd: &'a PathBuf,
    winwidth: usize,
    files: &'a Vec<PathBuf>,
) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a> {
    let file = File::open(path).unwrap();

    Ok(BufReader::new(file).lines().filter_map(move |line| {
        line.ok().and_then(|input| {
            if let Ok(tag) = TagInfo::parse(&path, &input) {
                Some(tag.format(&cwd, winwidth))
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
    }))
}


fn read_tag_files<'a>(
    cwd: &'a PathBuf,
    width: usize,
    files: &'a Vec<PathBuf>,
) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a> {

    let cwd = cwd.clone();

    let streams = files
        .clone()
        .into_iter()
        .map(move |path| read_tag_file(&path, &cwd, width, files))
        //                                    ^^^^ conflict here :/
        .flatten();

    let stream = Box::new(std::iter::empty()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>;
    let stream = streams.fold(
        stream,
        |acc, f| Box::new(acc.chain(f)) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>
    );

    Ok(stream)
}
```

For reference, here is the complete error output:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
   --> crates/maple_cli/src/cmd/tagfiles.rs:135:47
    |
135 |         .map(move |path| read_tag_file(&path, &cwd, winwidth, files))
    |                                               ^^^^
    |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined on the body at 135:14...
   --> crates/maple_cli/src/cmd/tagfiles.rs:135:14
    |
135 |         .map(move |path| read_tag_file(&path, &cwd, winwidth, files))
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that closure can access `cwd`
   --> crates/maple_cli/src/cmd/tagfiles.rs:135:47
    |
135 |         .map(move |path| read_tag_file(&path, &cwd, winwidth, files))
    |                                               ^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 125:19...
   --> crates/maple_cli/src/cmd/tagfiles.rs:125:19
    |
125 | fn read_tag_files<'a>(
    |                   ^^
note: ...so that return value is valid for the call
   --> crates/maple_cli/src/cmd/tagfiles.rs:129:13
    |
129 | ) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a> {
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You've moved `cwd` into the closure, so when you take a reference to it `&cwd` (the one you highlight), the created reference is only valid for the lifetime of the closure. However, you keep trying to use it in all the following steps, and then return something that's based on it.

Comment: For concrete help, it would be best to provide a [minimal, reproducing, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry I'm really unsure how to make it more minimal, I feel it would simplify the problem to the point of making it disappear, and I can't even compile it so forget about runnable :/
I've added more context (missing `read_tag_file` function). My question would be, how do I pass this reference to the closure to make it usable? It's a path passed down from the cmdline args, and I need to join a relative path with it down the stack.

Comment: The main issue isn't that this is not minimal enough, it's that it isn't reproducing. No one can get the same behavior you're citing from the code you posted. They had to guess at what `Result`, `PathBuf`, `read_tag_file`, `TagInfo` etc. were (some guesses are easier than others). The idea is to post something someone can copy and paste and see the same output as you.

Comment: @RomGrk usually getting the issue to trigger on the Playground ensures the code is at least complete enough to be fully understandable, meaning it's reproducible. Then you can try to strip irrelevant content to minimize it, but reproducibility is way more important than minimalism (though that shouldn't be abusive, posting kilobytes of code because you can't be arsed to reduce it is not acceptable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `read_tag_file` (or at least its signature) it's a bit difficult to really diagnose the issue.

I'd think the problem is `read_tag_file` somehow confuses the lifetimes of `path`, `files` and `cwd` (possibly the function uses lifetime elision or all three are bound to the same lifetime?), which means Rust assumes `&cwd` must be valid for `'a`, which it can not be since `cwd` only lives for as long as the closure is alive.

edit: after addition of the new function I can see the dependency better, and the issue is that you're copying either too much or not enough: you could bypass this problem by copying *more* at the cost of efficiency, but here your code is very close, you have two problems remaining, at least for this to compile (not sure the caller will be happy with it):

- you're cloning `cwd` inside the function, this means the `cwd` you're moving in the closure only lives for the function but the closure itself needs to outlive the function, you could just *not* clone cwd at all, it's already an `&PathBuf` which is exactly what you want
- then `files.clone()` clones paths individually, which means your `&path` is only valid inside the closure, but the output of the closure is borrow-ish (though I don't think it needs be), but anyway here again that's completely unnecessary, `files` is an `&[PathBuf]`, you can use it as-is

```rust
fn read_tag_files<'a>(
    cwd: &'a PathBuf,
    width: usize,
    files: &'a Vec<PathBuf>,
) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = String> + 'a> {
    let streams = files
        // don't copy the files
        .into_iter()
        .map(move |path| read_tag_file(&path, cwd, width, files))
        //                                    just use the cwd you have, it's fine as-is
        .flatten();

    let stream = Box::new(std::iter::empty()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>;
    let stream = streams.fold(
        stream,
        |acc, f| Box::new(acc.chain(f)) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item = String>>
    );

    Ok(stream)
}
```

Comment: I've added `read_tag_file`, but I still don't understand what the issue is. How would I  pass `cwd` in a form that would be usable down to `read_tag_file` and `tag.format`?

Comment: "I still don't understand what the issue is" the issue is that you return an iterator which depends on data *created* in the function (`cwd`) but which it doesn't own, so once the function ends that data goes away and the reference is invalid, which is not allowed.

Comment: I get what you mean. I've made it work by tweaking according to your answer. It's my first rust project so I relied on `.clone()` whenever I had ownership issues, that's a mistake here. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Relying on clone to make things work is fine, really, but then you really have to do that *everywhere* (or near that), if your see lifetime bounds crop up in your return values then you're back to having to deal with the borrow checker.

Comment: Got it. For anyone stumbling here, I also found this article that helped a lot to understand how to make things work: https://bryce.fisher-fleig.org/strategies-for-returning-references-in-rust/